# How can I recursively count files and folders in Windows with C#?

Tags: c#, recursion, filesystems, directory

***EDIT 8/8/2012:*** *I've made some significant changes to the code I'm using and would like some fresh help on one last problem I'm having.  I'm going to rewrite most of this question.*

I have a small program which iterates recursively through each file and folder under a target directory checking the names for specific characters.  It works just fine but I'm looking for help on how to make a specific method work faster.

Here's the code I'm currently using.  This is just a couple of lines from the method that kicks everything off:

```
if(getFullList(initialPathTB.Text))
            SearchFolder();
```

And these are the two methods you need to see:

```
private void SearchFolder()
{
    int      newRow;
    int      numItems = 0;

    numItems = itemsMaster.Length;

    for (int x = 0; x < numItems; x++)
    {
        if (hasIllegalChars(itemsMaster[x]) == true)
        {
            newRow = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[newRow].Cells[0].Value = itemsMaster[x];
            filesFound++;
        }
    }
}

private bool getFullList(string folderPath)
{
    try
    {
        if (checkBox17.Checked)
            itemsMaster = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(folderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        else
            itemsMaster = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(folderPath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        return true;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        if(folderPath[folderPath.Length - 1] != '\\')
            folderPath += @"\";
        if (e.Message == "Access to the path '" + folderPath + "' is denied.")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You do not have read permission for the following directory:\n\n\t" + folderPath + "\n\nPlease select another folder or log in as a user with read access to this folder.", "Access Denied", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            folderPath = folderPath.Substring(0, folderPath.Length - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            if (accessDenied == null)
                accessDenied = new StringBuilder("");
            accessDenied.AppendLine(e.Message.Substring(20, e.Message.Length - 32));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`initialPathTB.Text` is populated with something like "F:\COMMON\Administration".

**Here's my problem.**  When the top level that's passed to `folderPath` is one which the user does not have read access everything works fine.  When the top level *and all subordinate directories* are folders which the user has read access everything works fine again.  The issue lies with directories where the user has read access to the top level but does not for some child folder deeper within.  This is why `getFullList()` is a bool; if there are any UnauthorizedAccessExceptions then `itemsMaster` remains empty and `SearchFolder()` fails on `numItems = itemsMaster.Length;`.

What I'd like is to populate `itemsMaster` with every item within `folderPath` and simply skip the items for which the user doesn't have read access but I don't know how to do that without recursively crawling and checking each directory.

This code works *so much faster* than my old method so I'd rather not abandon it for something else entirely.  Is there any way to make the `Directory.GetFileSystemEntries()` method do what I want?

Comment: How long is it taking your program to count, compared to doing Folder Properties in Windows Explorer? Just a guess, but I'd expect that you won't be able to do it faster than Windows itself, which can be pretty slow on something that large.

Comment: Is the `ToString()` on `items[x]` even necessary? Just an unneeded function call that will cause lag, especially in a loop.

Comment: @JoeEnos - My method definitely takes much longer than if I check the folder properties via Windows Explorer.

Comment: Just out of interest, what does your program do, what does _"checking the names for specific character"_ mean? If you're checking the file names, it's probably almost  as expensive to execute the whole program as to count the files.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - It literally checks the file or folder name for characters that SharePoint won't allow but Windows will.  For example the & character.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Turns out you're right; that's just my brain being unnecessarily thorough.  That'll shave a few milliseconds off the run time.  :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson: `String.ToString` just returns itself, there are certainly more expensive functions in that loop like `Directory.Exists`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Actually that's a good point.  It might be faster overall to count the contents of each sub-folder with my method above and save all of those items' paths to an array, then check the array for illegal characters rather than accessing the file system again...

Answer (score 2):

```
Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(folderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length
```

or another option (with this option, keep in mind the first 3-5 elements in `fullstring` will be garbage text from the output which you should remove):

```
Process process = new Process();
List<string> fullstring = new List<string>();

process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args2) => fullstring.Add(args2.Data);

process.Start();

process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"dir /b /s c:\temp | find """" /v");
process.BeginOutputReadLine();

process.WaitForExit(10000); //or whatever is appropriate time

process.Close();
```

If you want to track down errors better, make these changes:

Declare `List<string> fullstring = new List<string>();` globally, then change the event handler of `OutputDataReceived` like below:

```
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
}

static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        fullstring.Add(e.Data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        //log exception
    }
}
```

Comment: But that would have a HUGE lag on a modern hard drive

Comment: @ColeJohnson - It _did_ take a while but not as long as my method did.

Comment: Unless you want to do this in unmanaged code, I don't think you can do this much faster than the above framework method.

Comment: If I use `Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(folderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` to populate an array but there are one or more sub-directories below `folderPath` for which the user doesn't have read access how would a catch clause handle the `UnauthorizedAccessException`?  Would it just list the first one and quit populating the list or would it continue on to the next file/directory?  And if it continues on is there any way for me to capture a list of directories that threw the exception?

Comment: Why can't I upvote your answer again?  I'll give you the checkmark once I've implemented your Process solution.

Comment: @jonnyp if you have followup questions you can post in comments and I'll try to answer.

Comment: I don't understand the line `process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args2) => fullstring.Add(args2.Data);` and I'm not sure where to begin on researching that, could you give me a link or a quick rundown on what exactly that's doing?  (Obviously it's instructing the Process to send the output to `fullstring`, but I don't understand the methodology.)

Comment: Is an anonymous delegate formed using a lambda expression. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383984.aspx

Comment: I can't seem to get `fullString` to populate.  If I put a breakpoint in at the `process.WaitForExit(10000);` line I can see a few errors under `process`, all of which are System.InvalidOperationException errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you copy/paste your code into the original question? Maybe I can spot something.

Comment: Yep.  I get solid output when I run that command in cmd.exe manually, is that my problem?  Should I use the full \\<server>\<path> address instead?

Comment: @JonnyP - No, your better bet is to use the mapped letter drive. Probably there is a permissions error here. Have you tried running your program with Administrator privileges? Also, see my edit above to help you better track down your exceptions.

Comment: I've never needed to use Admin privileges before and like I said I can get good output when using that command in cmd.exe.  Also I've made the changes you suggested and I can't seem to figure out where to go to check the log file... :\

Comment: Run the code in debug and check the output window. Or just set a breakpoint in the event handler.

Comment: If I have a breakpoint at `proc.WaitForExit(...);` I get nothing in the Output and `fullString` isn't populated in Locals.  If I put a breakpoint at `Debug.Writeline(...);` a cmd.exe window flashes when I initialize the routine and it never actually hits the breakpoint.  What am I doing wrong here?  **Edit:** If I don't have any breakpoints then the cmd.exe window flashes and nothing happens after that, also.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - I've made some pretty hefty changes to my code, would you mind taking another look at my question for me?

Answer (score 1):

You write that "I'd like the progress bar to actually indicate how far through the list of items the program is, so therefore I need a number of items to set the ProgressBar.Maximum property to."

This is kind of a specific desire, and I'm not sure its worthwhile in the given case.  If your ProgressBar is (say) 800 px wide, 1 percentage point would be 0.125px wide. For a list "over a hundred thousand items" -- let's make that a minimum of 100,000 -- you have to process 8,000 items to move the bar to move a single pixel. How much time does it take for your program to process 8,000 items? That will help you understand what kind of actual feedback you're giving the user. If it takes too long, it might look like things have hung, even if it's working.

If you're looking to give good user feedback, I'd suggest setting your ProgressBar's style to Marquee and providing a "Now checking file #*x*" textual indicator.

Comment: That's a fair point.  I'm also still pretty new to C# (as I'm sure everyone can tell from my code block above) and have been using this application as a learning experience as well.

Comment: I've made some pretty hefty changes to my code, would you mind taking another look at my question for me?